# In SDL, do I need to free the surface I got from SDL_GetWindowSurface?

Tags: c, sdl

In SDL, when I destroy a window with `SDL_DestroyWindow`, do I also need to call `SDL_FreeSurface` to release the surface that is associated with that window?

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow(/*...*/);
SDL_Surface *wsurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
/*...*/
SDL_FreeSurface(wsurface); /* <- do I also need this line? */
SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
```

It isn't clear to me if the surface needs to be manually released or if it gets released automatically when I destroy the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets released automatically. Here is the relevant [documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSurface):

> A new surface will be created with the optimal format for the window, if necessary. This surface will be freed when the window is destroyed. *Do not free this surface*.